# Order of symbol lookup in .so dependency graph

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, elf

Suppose I have a shared objects load-time dependency graph and symbol `foo` referenced in one of the .so. Suppose  also this symbol `foo` is defined in several other shared objects. My question is: which definition will be found, what is a look up order and where it is defined (in what standard, man page)?

Example:
Consider a dependency graph
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRwFM.png

where libraries listed in ldd order e.g.

```
ldd a.so
b.so
d.so
```

Lets assume `foo` defined in c.so and d.so and first referenced in f.so. My experimentation shows that implementation from d.so will be taken by the linker. It looks like that libraries are searched in [bfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_search) order. Is this right? Does this coincide with libraries loading order? I could not find this in any documentation and must be sure it is not implementation defined.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic linking is specified in the [ELF specfication](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/contents.html).  (Note that there are some really old PDFs and Postscript files floating around, but those are generally very outdated.)  Symbol lookup is described in section [Shared Object Dependencies](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch5.dynamic.html#shobj_dependencies):

> When resolving symbolic references, the dynamic linker examines the symbol tables with a breadth-first search. That is, it first looks at the symbol table of the executable program itself, then at the symbol tables of the `DT_NEEDED` entries (in order), and then at the second level `DT_NEEDED` entries, and so on.

(There are various extensions which alter this behavior.  The ELF specification itself defines the [`DF_SYMBOLIC` flag](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch5.dynamic.html#df_symbolic).)

This means that your question cannot be answered because your graph does not show the main executable, and it is unclear in which order multiple dependencies are searched (top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top).

Whether the lookup order matches the object loading order is implementation-defined because merely loading an object (without executing its initialization functions) is not something that has an observable effect according to the ELF specification.

[Initialization order](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch5.dynamic.html#init_fini) (the order in which initialization functions are executed) is less constrained than symbol lookup order because the order of `DT_NEEDED` entries does not matter to that. So in theory, it is possible that an implementation loads an initializes `d.so` before `b.so`, but the symbols from `b.so` interpose that of `d.so` because it comes first in the symbol search order (due to the way the `DT_NEEDED` entries are ordered).